# Analytical solution for wall eigenvalue analysis

Tags: structural-analysis, modal-analysis, eigenvalue-analysis

I have a wall with the bottom end of it fixed to the ground. I want to derive from first principles the frequencies and mode shapes of the structure.

I know that I will need to start with the following formula:

$K-\omega^2M=0$

And I know how to do that for a cantilever column.

But wall is a different thing than column because it is an area element instead of a line element. And I don't know how to generate the correct expression for $K$ and $M$ for a continuum area element.

How to proceed with the analytical solution for wall eigenvalue analysis?

Note: I am not looking for a FEM solution.

Comment: A wall will behave no differently to a cantilever column, other than that it's simpler as it can only buckle in one direction. (As to the formula, I have no idea I'm afraid. All of my theoretical eigenvalue knowledge has been forgotten, I only use FEM these days.)

Comment: @AndyT, since the wall has more DOF so I believe it can exhibit twisting ( torsion) effect when column can't?

Comment: I suppose so, if you're looking at more than one mode. If you only want the first mode, a wall is simple; for later modes you are correct that it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "wall" would be referred as a "plate" in the technical literature. The eigenvalue problem for a plate is significantly more complicated than a beam, but similar ideas.

I would suggest that you look for a book on "vibrations of continuous systems", for example: http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471771716.html

There are also specific books dedicated entirely to plates, e.g. https://www.crcpress.com/Vibrations-of-Shells-and-Plates-Third-Edition/Soedel/p/book/9780824756291  however they may be hard to understand without sufficient background.

Comment: Would you like to screenshot the relevant portions from the book, or refer to a link that we can actually access the information?

Comment: The relevant portions would be an entire chapter, maybe 2. Too much to screenshot. One freely available resource is  https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19700009156.pdf  but it is pretty technical without very much background material.

Comment: Would you like to update the answer to make it a) contains reference to the PDF that one can access, b) even better, to screenshot or type the relevant portion out and put it in your answer?

Comment: Would you like the accept that fact that the answer to the question you've asked would cover at least a week in a graduate level class, and thus is way too long for me to type out here. If you don't like my answer then I'm sorry but I can't do anything else for you. All of the references I found were just by typing "vibration of plates" into google.  If you don't like them, try searching yourself.  Maybe there is another one you'll like better.